# Where to see android.R.layout layout examples?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am starting Android development and have followed some examples on the web that use layouts in android.R.layout. However, I want to know if there is a way to see what each of these standard layouts looks like and whether I can use them without developing a new layout of my own.

How do I see what each of these standard layouts offers?

Comment: You may find all standard layouts in Android SDK, which is installed on your PC.

Comment: If you setup correctly Eclipse for Android, then it provides a way to visualize the xml layout in Graphical mode.

Comment: :-/ I am using Intellij IDEA Community Edition. But thanks, perhaps I will look into that.

Comment: I have installed Eclipse correctly but when I go in the r.layout folder in the android folder in my project ( I am using Android 4.2), my graphical editor gives me an error saying : Android XML Editor cannot process this input.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what site you are looking at and if they even offer the XML their layout is composed of. This is a reference for reusing layouts, maybe even some of your own:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

To preview the XML, I'm guessing you'll use the UI designer in Eclipse.

Comment: I am very sorry, I specified my question incorrectly, but that probably comes from being an Android noob. I actually meant the standard layouts in android.R.layout. Sorry, going to change my question.